# Mask Objects in Depth Map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, vision, object-recognition

i'm am currently trying out object recognition using surface matching using Point Pair Features, based on [1]. Furthermore in [2] already recognized objects are masked out of the depth map, to allow easier detection of occluded objects.
The Object is in PLY Format, as well as the scene. The first object should be detected with a certain pose and rotation and should then be masked out in the image to not be sampled by the detector anymore. How could you realise this efficiently (or at all)?

My first idea was to 'subtract' the models point cloud from the scene point cloud, but if the pointcloud of the model does not match with the scanned scene's point cloud, this would not work. Even if the model had a similar point cloud, the rotation of the object might shift points, so that they can not be subtracted too easily.

I probably lack some background in this topic, so if there is any more information needed, please tell me (I know this is very general).

Thank you in advance!

[1] Drost *et al.*, "Model Globally, Match Locally: Efficient and Robust 3D Object Recognition"

[2] Salas-Moreno *et al.*, "SLAM++: Simultaneous Localisation and Mapping at the Level of Objects"

Comment: I did not ask for code, did I? I was just asking how one could achieve it in practice. I did not ask for a "code writing service" nor do I want a "code writing service".

Comment: if I understand correctly, the problem is that the x and y coordinates of the 3d model are not aligned with the xy grid of the depth map?

Comment: Well, that would probably be the case if the model point cloud would habe a similar point cloud as the scene. But I would't evento expect them to be similar.. It would be enough to mask out the silhouette the object has from that perspective, but how could I computed the silhouette?